# how to get session value in external js file in asp.net

Tags: javascript

I use the session variable in default.aspx.vb page like this `Session("dowloa")="True"` .
        but i get in ss.js file like this 
`var ViewOnly =  '<%=Session("dowloa") %>'` i put alert msg the viewonly 
it show like this `"'<%=Session("dowloa") %>'"` but no value. how we get session value in external js file

Actually we get like in alert "True"